# Copy and paste a feature in QGIS at the current mouse position (paste in place): not on top of the feature copied

Tags: qgis-3

Is there a way to copy a feature and paste it to a new position using the mouse?

At the moment, I have to do this in two steps:
 1. Paste on top of the existing, copied feature and then
 2. Move it to a new location

This is double handling (and pasting directly on top of an existing feature primes the layer to have duplicate geometries if not especially careful to move the pasted feature straight away).

Answer (score 2):

Function is called *Copy and Move Feature* and is available for point, line or polygon features.  Example with line features here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apDM1yNjoZg

The advanced digitising toolbar needs to be turned on to access the button for this function.